# Docker image Rhel5.4/Rhel6.5

Tags: docker

I have a software package running on RHEL5.4

Can I make a docker image of my software which can run on user machine with RHEL6.5?

Comment: Have you tried anything or googled it?

Answer (score 0):

**Some comments first**

You may already know that but just in case: a container should not be seen as a Virtual Machine. This is more like an isolation for an application.

I wanted to start with this remark because your container won't exactly be a RHEL. You have to start with a simple and minimal base, identify the libraries you really need and try to build the smallest possible image like that.

Last remark (it was not clear from your question) your host might be an OS and your container might be another OS. (you can run Ubuntu containers on a Windows host for example)

**CentOS**

You might want to look at CentOS: https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/

CentOS is really close to a Red Hat in terms of libraries and packages. I would then recommend to start from a CentOS image.

I hope it helps